# Disappearing parameters from method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm developping an Android application but I think this might be Java specific.

From a fragment I call a static method. In the fragment I set all the paramters for the static method. When I debug the app the parameters are all set but when I get to the static method the paramters are not set.

This is the method from the Fragment (it's happening in the calling of `GPSTracker.distanceInMetersFromTo`):

```
public void updateDistance(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longtitude = location.getLongitude();

    List<ListInspectieItem> newList = new ArrayList<ListInspectieItem>();
    List<ListInspectieItem> oldList = adapter.getValues();

    for (ListInspectieItem l : oldList) {
        double latitudeFrom = latitude;
        double longtitudeFrom = longtitude;
        double latitudeTo = Double.valueOf(l.latitude);
        double longtitudeTo = Double.valueOf(l.longtitude);

        double afst = GPSTracker.distanceInMetersFromTo(
                latitudeFrom, 
                longtitudeFrom, 
                latitudeTo, 
                longtitudeTo 
        );
        newList.add(new ListInspectieItem(
                l.inspectieSoort,
                l.opdrachtIdentificatie,
                l.bronsysteem,
                l.latitude,
                l.longtitude,
                round(afst, 2)
        ));
    }

    ...

    adapter.changeList(newList);
}
```

This is the static method:

```
public static double distanceInMetersFromTo(double latitudeFrom, double longtitudeFrom, double latitudeTo, double longtitudeTo){
    double R = 6371e3; // metres
    double phi1 = doubleToRadian(latitudeFrom);
    double phi2 = doubleToRadian(latitudeTo);

    double deltaphi  = doubleToRadian(latitudeFrom-latitudeTo);
    double deltadelta = doubleToRadian(longtitudeFrom-longtitudeTo);

    double a = Math.sin(deltadelta/2) * Math.sin(deltaphi/2) +
            Math.cos(phi1) * Math.cos(phi2) *
                    Math.sin(deltadelta/2) * Math.sin(deltadelta/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

    return R * c;
}
```

The parameters `latitudeFrom` and `longtitudeFrom` are both set but the `latitudeTo` and longtitudeTo are both not set.

When I call the method all the variable have a value. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, it might be some Java magic that I don't know of.

## Update:

To clarify it a bit more here are two screenshots during debug:

The call to the static method from the fragment. You can see that the paramters are all set.
[image: Fragment screenshot]

This is the static method `distanceInMetersFromTo` where you can see that only the `latitudeFrom` and the `longtitudeFrom` are set.

[image: static method screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `parseDouble(l.latitude)` instead of `Double.valueOf(l.latitude)`? The latter returns a `Double` object, while the former returns a primitive `double` which is the data type of the variable to which you've assigned it.
Autounboxing should've taken care of that, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I believe it is beter to use `parseDouble(String)` So I did change it, but it didn't solve it.